# Zend Framework  call to undefined function token_get_all()

Tags: zend-framework

i am using php version 5.3.5. i am using zend framework using in xampp server.i can create project and controller using zend framework(1.11.11) but i cant create a action.error displaying below

Fatal error: call to undefined function token_get_all() in D:\www\xampp\htdocs\zf\library\zend\Reflection\File.phpon line 301

(using command prompt)

Answer (score 5):

Strange. You probably don't have the [tokenizer extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tokenizer.php) available or enabled, however on 5.3.5 it ought to be in the core and enabled by default. Check your phpinfo at the tokenizer section.

Edit: Short googling found me this: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=3900

Comment: You saved my ass tonight, I have a Laravel project due tomorrow and Ampps did not have tokenizer.so enabled by default. I would not have thought of this, thank you.

Comment: Ampps has quite a lot of extensions disabled by default, it'always worth to go PHP > PHP Extension in control panel and see what's checked. With a Silex app I needed to enable two extensions disabled by default.

Comment: That link is dead now, and it's not available through archive.org either. It's best to include the relevant info directly in your answer so it can be preserved when external links go down.